# The method listener(Object) is ambiguous for the type SimpleStepBuilder

Tags: spring

I'm using a class which implements SkipPolicy for reader and a class which extends ItemListenerSupport for writer. Below is my spring batch configuration

```
    SimpleStepBuilder simpleStepBuilder = steps.get("employeeJob")
                .allowStartIfComplete(true)
                .<Employee, Employee>chunk(3)
                .reader(employeeFlatFileItemReader) 
                .listener(new EmployeeSkipPolicy())
                .processor(employeeProcessor);
        ItemWriter writer = employeeWriter;
        simpleStepBuilder.writer(writer).listener(new 
        EmployeeFileItemListener());
        step = simpleStepBuilder.build();

public class EmployeeSkipPolicyimplements SkipPolicy
public class EmployeeFileItemListenerextends ItemListenerSupport

The method listener(Object) is ambiguous for the type 
SimpleStepBuilder is thrown 
on line - simpleStepBuilder.writer(writer).listener(new 
EmployeeFileItemListener());
```

Please help me on how to resolve this as i need both skip policy and writer listener to process the csv file

Instead of using the above ItemListenerSupport, can we extend this class and use it???

```
public class EmployeeFileItemListener implements 
 ItemWriteListener<Employee> {
```

Thanks

Current Modified Code:

```
SimpleStepBuilder simpleStepBuilder = steps.get("employeeJob")
      .allowStartIfComplete(true) .<Employee, Employee>chunk(3) 
      .reader(employeeFlatFileItemReader) 
      .faultTolerant().skipPolicy(new EmployeeSkipPolicy()) 
      .processor(employeeProcessor); 
simpleStepBuilder.writer(writer).listener(new 
     EmployeeFileItemListener()); 
public class EmployeeSkipPolicy implements SkipPolicy 
public class EmployeeFileItemListener implements 
   ItemWriteListener<Employee> {
```

Comment: Why is your `EmployeeSkipPolicy` registered as a listener? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @M.Deinum The error is not thrown in the skipolicy. However thanks for the catch and have changed the code - .faultTolerant().skipPolicy(new EmployeeSkipPolicy()). SkipPolicy for reader and EmployeeFileItemListener  for writer. The writer throws the error. so i changed it to ItemWriteListener...will that be ok ?

Comment: You changed what to what? That is totally unclear? Also why a custom skip policy? You can set the skip limit, and errors to ignore with just configuration. You should set the listener on the step not the writer. So right after the `faultTolerant` part.

Comment: @M.Deinum Is this code is correct?    SimpleStepBuilder simpleStepBuilder = steps.get("employeeJob")
           .allowStartIfComplete(true)
           .<Employee, Employee>chunk(3)
           .reader(employeeFlatFileItemReader) 
           .faultTolerant().skipPolicy(new EmployeeSkipPolicy())
           .processor(employeeProcessor);   
         simpleStepBuilder.writer(writer).listener(new 
        EmployeeFileItemListener());

public class EmployeeSkipPolicy implements SkipPolicy
public class EmployeeFileItemListener implements ItemWriteListener<Employee> {

Comment: Please don't post code as comments, as that is totally unreadable.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have added the code above in the original post. Please check

Comment: If i add the listener it throws ambiguos error

Comment: What I don't get is you should just be able to use `ItemListenerSupport<Employee>` that should just work (unless you forgot initially the generics. Also you can just define your own class and use the `@OnSkipIn*` annotations, no need to use the interface.